# ng-fullcalendar need to show only events with specific id's in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar

I'm trying to create an scheluder for my angular application with ng-fullcalendar. I got it installed without any problem but i want only render some specific ID's from my event.service. This is my NgOnInit:

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data[0].id);
       this.calendarOptions = {
         editable: true,
         eventLimit: false,
         header: {
           left: 'prev,next today',
           center: 'title',
           right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
         },
         defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
         events: data,
       };
     });
   }
```

My events.service looks like:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
@Injectable()
export class EventService {
    public getEvents(): Observable<any> {
        const dateObj = new Date();
        const yearMonth = dateObj.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1);
        let data: any = [{
            id: 999,
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: yearMonth + '-01'
        },
        {
            id: 998,
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: yearMonth + '-07',
            end: yearMonth + '-10'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: yearMonth + '-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            id: 998,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: yearMonth + '-16T16:00:00'
        }
       ];
        return Observable.of(data);
    }
};
```

At the current situation al those events are rendered in my view. What do i need to change on this code to only show events with the id '999' for example.

Thanks for those who took time to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter using this:
data.filter( ev => ev.id == '999');

So on your ngOnInit will become like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data[0].id);
   this.calendarOptions = {
     editable: true,
     eventLimit: false,
     header: {
       left: 'prev,next today',
       center: 'title',
       right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
     },
     defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
     events: data.filter( ev => ev.id == '999'),
   };
 });
   }
```

You can also start with an empty list of events and later use a method to insert them.

```
this._calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvents', #your Filtered events#, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! it works directly, your second option either!